# Boost: undefined reference to '__xstat64', '__lxstat64', '__errno_location' error

Tags: linux, boost, makefile, cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to convert android ndk c++ code from 32-bit to 64-bit. But facing 64-bit related errors while compiling. Below are the errors during the linking process:

```
/opt/boost_1_59_0_android_x86_64/libs/libFramework.ThirdParty.Boost.Filesystem.a(operations.o):libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp:function boost::filesystem::detail::canonical(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*): error: undefined reference to '__xstat64'

/opt/boost_1_59_0_android_x86_64/libs/libFramework.ThirdParty.Boost.Filesystem.a(operations.o):libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp:function boost::filesystem::detail::canonical(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*): error: undefined reference to '__errno_location'

/opt/boost_1_59_0_android_x86_64/libs/libFramework.ThirdParty.Boost.Filesystem.a(operations.o):libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp:function boost::filesystem::detail::symlink_status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*): error: undefined reference to '__lxstat64'

/opt/boost_1_59_0_android_x86_64/libs/libFramework.ThirdParty.Boost.Filesystem.a(operations.o):libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp:function boost::filesystem::detail::symlink_status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*): error: undefined reference to '__errno_location'

/opt/boost_1_59_0_android_x86_64/libs/libFramework.ThirdParty.Boost.Filesystem.a(operations.o):libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp:function boost::filesystem::detail::read_symlink(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*): error: undefined reference to '__errno_location'

/opt/boost_1_59_0_android_x86_64/libs/libFramework.ThirdParty.Boost.Filesystem.a(operations.o):libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp:function boost::filesystem::detail::read_symlink(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*): error: undefined reference to '__errno_location'

/opt/boost_1_59_0_android_x86_64/libs/libFramework.ThirdParty.Boost.Filesystem.a(operations.o):libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp:function boost::filesystem::detail::copy_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*): error: undefined reference to '__xstat64'

/opt/boost_1_59_0_android_x86_64/libs/libFramework.ThirdParty.Boost.Filesystem.a(operations.o):libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp:function boost::filesystem::detail::copy_file(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::detail::copy_option, boost::system::error_code*): error: undefined reference to '__xstat64'

/opt/boost_1_59_0_android_x86_64/libs/libFramework.ThirdParty.Boost.Filesystem.a(operations.o):libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp:function boost::filesystem::detail::create_directories(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*): error: undefined reference to '__xstat64'

/opt/boost_1_59_0_android_x86_64/libs/libFramework.ThirdParty.Boost.Filesystem.a(operations.o):libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp:function boost::filesystem::detail::permissions(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::perms, boost::system::error_code*): error: undefined reference to '__lxstat64'

/opt/boost_1_59_0_android_x86_64/libs/libFramework.ThirdParty.Boost.Filesstem.a(operations.o):libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp:function boost::filesystem::detail::remove(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*): error: undefined reference to '__lxstat64'

/opt/boost_1_59_0_android_x86_64/libs/libFramework.ThirdParty.Boost.Filesstem.a(operations.o):libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp:function boost::filesystem::detail::remove_all(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*): error: undefined reference to '__lxstat64'

/opt/boost_1_59_0_android_x86_64/libs/libFramework.ThirdParty.Boost.Filesystem.a(path.o):libs/filesystem/src/path.cpp:function boost::filesystem::path::codecvt(): error: undefined reference to 'std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t> const& std::use_facet<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t> >(std::locale const&)'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xaqs01wyyab57un/boost-build-output.txt?dl=0) is the link for boost build output.

Comment: Have you re-built the Boost libraries to be 64-bit, instead of 32-bit?

Comment: Yes I recompiled boost to 64-bit. This is the build command for reference.


  `./bjam -d+2 -j 32 --reconfigure target-os=android toolset=clang-x86_64 include=/opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x link=static,shared cxxflags=-fPIC cflags=-fPIC -a -link=static variant=release threading=multi --without-context --without-coroutine --prefix=/workspace/aivi-common/boost-android/x86_64 install`

Comment: It seems like there is still some compiler settings differences between your Boost build and the other C++ code you are building. Perhaps, something like Boost not rebuilding completely, or Boost not using the android compiler. It may help if you post your Boost Build output and CMake/make configuration in your question.

Comment: This looks a lot like you've built boost for a higher `minSdkVersion` than your app is using.

Comment: @squareskittles, I have added link where you can download the file. The file has the logs for boost build output command